# Probability of binary subsequence

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be an $iid$ binary sequence of length $n$

$X = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ with $x_i \in \{0,1\}, i \in \{0,1,...,n\}$

Let $P(X_i = 1) = p$

Let $Y \subset X$ be an invariant subsequence of length $l$, e.g. $Y = (X_{k+1} = a,X_{k+2} = a,..., X_{k+l}=a)$, $a \in \{0,1\}$.

What is the probability distribution over having at least one invariant sequence of length $l$ in $X$ of length $n$?

**Example 1:**
Given $X$ has 50 binary numbers. What is the probability of having at least one sequence 12 consecutive 0's or 1's?

**Example 2:**
For $n=100$. What is the probability of having at least one invariant sequence of length $l > 10 $.

Comment: hint : choose the position of the first element of your sequence of length $l$, and do not forget the element just before must be of a different type.

Comment: check out https://www.csun.edu/~hcmth031/tlroh.pdf